# Array of key/value pairs to object

Tags: javascript

I want to change this

```
var data = [60, rose, 40, rose1, 20, rose2];
```

to this

```
var data: [{
  value: 60,
  name: 'rose'
}, {
  value: 40,
  name: 'rose1'
}, {
  value: 20,
  name: 'rose2'
}];
```

Comment: you cant, `rose` is a variable, and wont be in the array, only it's value. you would need to use it as a string `"rose"`

Comment: CodeiSir, but this is for chart , that mean cannot do this way ?

Comment: Write an utility method to convert the data.

Comment: We're assuming that `rose` is something other than a string. It might be that @Syafiqapit just forgot to add quotes around it.

Comment: thank guys for response @kkkkk ....thank i try the method below answer

Comment: Referring to the original title, "Array to json style", please use correct terminology. Otherwise you will confuse yourself and others. JSON has a very specific meaning: it's a string-based data interchange format. What you are talking about here is a plain old JavaScript object.

Comment: @torazaburo but someone might be searching the same keywords he used in his title, because he is a beginner and not find it with the new title, because he does not know the words yet. "JSON-Style" is OK I think^^

Comment: @CodeiSir Unlikely.If you are searching for "rose", but think it's called "orchid", then you should not be surprised your search for orchid does not return information about roses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```js
var data = [60, "rose", 40, "rose1", 20, "rose2"]

var dataObj = []
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=2) {
  dataObj.push({
    value: data[i],
    name: data[i + 1]
  })
}

// Demo Output
document.write(JSON.stringify(dataObj))
```

Comment: i try this method, will inform you if success.Thank

Comment: you can press "Run code snippet" below the code to see the result ;) If you need some help just tell me

Comment: Simpler: `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) ..`

Comment: @Syafiqapit did it work for you? If you need more help just tell me

Comment: @CodeiSir thank so much :) the code run as i want . you are genius ..Thank, n happy new year guys that response my question.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the completeness, works even for uneven items:

```js
var data = [60, "rose", 40, "rose1", 20, "rose2", 30],
    object = data.reduce(function (r, a, i, d) {
        if (i % 2) {
            r[d[i - 1]] = a;
        }
        return r;
    }, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: thank so much :) i run very used code from codesir, will try your code :) happy new year